# How to add enemy sprites that follow player

Tags: python, pygame

I am extremely new to pygame and honestly, have never learnt about it (only the very basics of python) but I have to make a game for a project.

I tried to add the enemy sprite by referring to the other question and answers here but I don't really know what codes are needed, what I should delete and how I should change the codes to fit my own and make my game run.

I'm hoping that someone can adjust my code so that it can work.

This is what I have so far for the enemy. I know that more codes are supposed to be added but I don't know what and where to add them.

```
class Enemy(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 20])
        self.image.fill(red)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

    def move(self, player):
        dx, dy = self.rect.x - player.rect.x, self.rect.y - player.rect.y
        dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)
        dx, dy = dx / dist, dy / dist
        self.rect.x += dx * self.speed
        self.rect.y += dy * self.speed
```

Right now, the game can run but there is no enemy sprite. I thought I had to add these lines too

```
enemy = Enemy(50, 50)
all_sprite_list.add(enemy)
```

but it just makes a bunch of error messages show up. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The enemy has to "know" the walls (same like the player) and an enemy `.speed` ha to be defined:

```py
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, speed, walls):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 20])
        self.image.fill(red)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

        self.speed = speed # speed of the enemy
        self.walls = walls # walls for the collision test
```

Define an enemy:

```py
enemy = Enemy(500, 500, 1, wall_list)
all_sprite_list.add(enemy)
```

In your code the movement is computed in the opposite direction. Invert the calculation of the movement vector.
Set `self.move_x` and `self.move_y` in `Enemy.move`:

```py
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # [...]

    def move(self, player):
        dx, dy = player.rect.x - self.rect.x, player.rect.y - self.rect.y
        dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)
        dx, dy = dx / dist, dy / dist
        self.move_x = dx * self.speed
        self.move_y = dy * self.speed
```

Add a collision test to the `Enemy` object, similar that one of the `Player` object:

```py
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # [...]

        def update(self):

        self.rect.x += round(self.move_x)
        block_collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)
        for block in block_collide:
            if self.move_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            else:
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right

        self.rect.y += round(self.move_y)
        block_collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)
        for block in block_collide:
            if self.move_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom
```

Move the enemy, before the sprites are updated, because `.move_x` and `.move_y` have to be set before:

```py
while run:

    # [...]

    enemy.move(player)
    all_sprite_list.update()
```

[image]